# Performance of walking directory structure vs reading file with contents of ls (or similar command) for performing search

Tags: python

Is it better to walk a directory structure when performing multiple searches or is it a good idea to catalog the directory structure (in a file or memory) and then operate on that catalog?  Or are there other methods which are better suited which I haven't hit upon?

I have a 3.5TB external HDD with thousands of files. 
I have a set of files which list the contents of a directory. These listing files hold a folder name, filenames and file sizes. 
I want to search the external HDD for the files in these listing files. If a file is found I then want to check and see if the file size of the actual file matches that in the listing file.

This process will cover about 1000 listing files and probably 10s of thousands of actual files.

A listing file would have contents like

```
folder: SummerPhotos
name: IMG0096.jpg, length: 6589
name: IMG0097.jpg, length: 6489
name: IMG0098.jpg, length: 6500
name: IMG0099.jpg, length: 6589
name: BeachPhotos/IMG0100.jpg, length, 34892
name: BeachPhotos/IMG0101.jpg, length, 34896
```

I like the offline processing of the listing files with a file which lists the contents of the external HDD because then I can perform this operation on a faster computer (as the hard drive is on an old computer acting as a server) or split the listing files over several computers and split up the work. Plus I think that continually walking the directory structure is about as inefficient as you can get and putting unnecessary wear on the hardware.

Walk pseudo code:

```
 for each listing file
      get base_foldername,filelist
 for root,subfolder,files in os.walk(/path/to/3.5TBdrive)
      if base_foldername in subfolder
              for file in filelist
                  if file in files
                      if file.size == os.path.getsize(file)
                          dosomething
                      else
                          somethingelse
                  else
                      not_found
```

For the catalog file method I'm thinking of dumping a recursive 'ls' to file and then pretty much doing a string search on that file. I'll extract the filesize and perform a match there.

My 'ls -RlQ' dump file is 11MB in size with ~150k lines. If there is a better way to get the required data I'm open to suggestions. I'm thinking of using the os.walk() to compile a list and create my own file in a format I like vs trying to parse my ls command.

I feel like I should be doing somethign to make my college professors proud and making a hashtable or balanced tree, but feel like the effort to implement that will take longer than simply brute forcing the solution w cpu cycles.

OS: Linux

preferred programming language: Python 2/3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to walk a directory structure when performing multiple
>   searches or is it a good idea to catalog the directory structure (in a
>   file or memory) and then operate on that catalog?

If you just want to check if the file exists or the directory structure is not too complex, I suggest you to just use your filesystem. You're basically duplicating the work that it already does anyway and this **will** lead to problems in the future, as complexity always does.

I don't see any point using hashtables or balanced trees for in-program data structures - this is also what your filesystem already does. What you should instead do to speed up lookups is to design a deep directory structure instead of a few single directories that contain thousands of files. There are filesystems that choke while trying to list directories with dozens of thousands of files and it is a better idea to limit yourself to a few thousands and create a new level of directory depth should you exceed it.

For example, if you want to keep logs of your internet-wide scanning research, if you use a single file for each host you scanned, you don't want to create a directory `scanning-logs` with files such as `1.1.1.1.xml`, `1.1.1.2.xml` and so on. Instead, naming such as `scanning-logs/1/1/1.1.1.1.xml` is a better idea.

Also, watch out for the inode limit! I was once building a large file-based database on EXT4 filesystem. One day I started getting error messages like "no space left on device" even though I clearly had quite a lot of space left. The real reason was that I created too many inodes - the limit can be manually set while creating a volume.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you would use your filesystem instead of using some sort of in program data structure. I'll be searching for thousands of files and putting this burden on my filesystem and hardware seems a bit ridiculous. I could have misinterpreted your answer.

Comment: Well, if you're looking for a file, you probably already know more or less what you're looking for, right? My point is that perhaps a better directory structure/naming scheme will help you.